# Combining ASM with non-asm code (or SwapInt64 ASM function needed)

Tags: delphi, assembly, pascal, inline-assembly

I need to process a file that is coming from the old Mac era (old Motorola CPU). The bytes are big endian so I have a function that swaps and Int64 to Intel little endian. The function is ASM and works on 32 bit CPU but not on 64. For 64 bit I have a different function that is not ASM. I want to combine the functions using IFDEF. Can I do this? Will it be a problem?

```
interface 

function SwapInt64(Value: Int64): Int64; assembler;  

implementation

{$IFDEF CPUx86}        
function SwapInt64(Value: Int64): Int64; assembler;        { Does not work on 64 bit }                                                                      { 
asm
 MOV     EDX,[DWORD PTR EBP + 12]
 MOV     EAX,[DWORD PTR EBP + 8]
 BSWAP   EAX
 XCHG    EAX,EDX
 BSWAP   EAX
end;

{$else}

 function SwapInt64 (Value: Int64): Int64;
 var P: PInteger;
 begin
  Result: = (Value shl 32) or (Value shr 32);
  P: = @Result;
  P ^: = (Swap (P ^) shl 16) or (Swap (P ^ shr 16));
  Inc (P);
  P ^: = (Swap (P ^) shl 16) or (Swap (P ^ shr 16));
 end;
{$ENDIF}
```

I think the compiler will correctly compile/call the appropriate function no matter if one is ASM and the other is Pascal.

Comment: Mac uses little endian too. Are you actually looking for network to host functions? Why do you feel the need to reimplement them? Why do you want to use asm? Isn't that what is causing you problems? If you used Pascal you'd be home and dry?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Sorry. I mean 'old Mac'. The one with big endian (sparc).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - please see clarifications related to the provenience of the data (old mac)

Comment: Unless perf matters, I'd just use Pascal.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-the ASM function should be faster. Right? IF POSSIBLE I would like to keep the asm on 32 bits. The files could be big (1-40GB). And all data needs to be swapped!!!!! The asm function MIGHT improve the speed a bit.

Comment: Have you timed it. The asm might be slower! It might not be. But don't optimise without timing

Comment: If you are reading large files from disk, that's going to determine the performance

Comment: Consider that for x64 input parameter is in RCX register, result in RAX. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention

Comment: FWIW, there is no problem at all using the condtionals. I do this all the time. many of the functions in my BigInteger and Decimal units are either pure Pascal, win32 assembler or win64 assembler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are proposing is perfectly fine. It is a quite reasonable approach.

If you want a 64 bit swap in asm, for x64, that's quite simple:

```
function SwapInt64(Value: Int64): Int64;
asm
  MOV    RAX,RCX
  BSWAP  RAX
end;
```

Combine this with the 32 bit version using conditional, as you have done in the question.

```
function SwapInt64(Value: Int64): Int64;
{$IF Defined(CPUX86)}
asm
 MOV     EDX,[DWORD PTR EBP + 12]
 MOV     EAX,[DWORD PTR EBP + 8]
 BSWAP   EAX
 XCHG    EAX,EDX
 BSWAP   EAX
end;
{$ELSEIF Defined(CPUX64)}
asm
  MOV    RAX,RCX
  BSWAP  RAX
end;
{$ELSE}
  {$Message Fatal 'Unsupported architecture'}
{$ENDIF}
```

Or include a Pascal implementation in the `{$ELSE}` block.

Comment: Thanks David. This will do it!

Answer (score 5):

The approach of swapping the bytes in a separate routine that cannot be inlined is a bit silly if performance is what you're after.

A better way to a assume you've got a block of data and all dword/qwords in it need to have their endianness changed.

This would look something like this.

For dwords

```
function SwapDWords(var Data; size: cardinal): boolean;
{ifdef CPUX64}
asm
  //Data in RCX, Size in EDX
  xor EAX,EAX //failure
  test EDX,3 
  jz @MultipleOf4
@error:
  ret
@MultipleOf4
  neg EDX    //Count up instead of down
  jz  @done
  ADD RCX,RDX      
@loop
  mov R8d, [RCX+RDX]
  bswap R8d
  mov [RCX+RDX],R8d  
  add RDX,4   //add is faster than inc on modern processors
  jnz @loop
@done:
  inc EAX  //success
  ret
end;
```

For qwords

```
function SwapQWords(var Data; size: cardinal): boolean;
{ifdef CPUX64}
asm
  //Data in RCX, Size in EDX
  xor EAX,EAX //failure
  test EDX,7 
  jz @MultipleOf8
@error:
  ret
@MultipleOf8
  neg EDX    //Count up instead of down
  jz  @done
  ADD RCX,RDX      
@loop
  mov R8, [RCX+RDX]
  bswap R8
  mov [RCX+RDX],R8
  add RDX,8   //add is faster than inc on modern processors
  jnz @loop
@done:
  inc EAX  //success
  ret
end;
```

If you're already on 64 bit, then you have SSE2, and can use the 128-bit SSE registers.
Now you can process 4 dwords at a time, effectively unrolling the loop 4 times.
See: http://www.asmcommunity.net/forums/topic/?id=29743

```
   movntpd xmm5,[RCX+RDX]  //non-temporal move to avoid polluting the cache
   movdqu xmm0, xmm5
   movdqu xmm1, xmm5
   pxor    xmm5, xmm5
   punpckhbw xmm0, xmm5 ; interleave '0' with bytes of original
   punpcklbw xmm1, xmm5 ;  so they become words
   pshuflw xmm0, xmm0, 27 ; swap the words by shuffling
   pshufhw xmm0, xmm0, 27 ;//27 = B00_01_10_11
   pshuflw xmm1, xmm1, 27
   pshufhw xmm1, xmm1, 27
   packuswb xmm1, xmm0 ; make the words back into bytes.
   movntpd [RCX+RDX], xmm1  //non-temporal move to keep the cache clean.
```

Comment: Passing count or length would allow you to avoid param validity checks. As regards performance, it's a little premature to make judgements. If the buffer is on a disk then that's what counts. And there's no evidence that the data is homogenous. Clearly if it is homogenous and in memory, then looping in asm will be best.

Comment: @Johan +1 for your nice answer. Unfortunately, in my case it won't work. I read a format with complex structure so the data is 'mixed'. I don't have a single block of dwords. I have all kind of data: integers, dwords, booleans, words, etc.

Comment: @Frosty In that case, I doubt that asm vs Pascal makes much difference in terms of perf. As it happens though, the asm versions are actually simpler to write! Although you need to write multiple version. Anyway, the decisions are yours.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use either [LEToN](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/leton.html)() or [BEtoN](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/beton.html)()

Use the LE variant if the data is little endian (e.g. 32 or 64-bits x86 mac, modern arm), use the BE if the source data (e.g. file from disk) is in big endian format.

Depending on the used architecture a swap or "nothing" will be inlined, usually a fairly optimal one for single conversions. For block oriented solutions see the posted SSE code (or Agner Fog's)

Comment: Leton/beton is for Freepascal not for Delphi. I am not sure it will work on Delphi. I will have to check it.

Comment: Using Delphi cpu defines and assumptions about calling conventions might fail on specially non windows FPC targets. Did you benchmark your program using both the asm function and pascal function and does it really matter that much?